# Заполнить массив от левого верхнего вниз зигзагом С++

Tags: c++, массивы

Помогите с программой, конечно работает корректно но выводит результат вверх ногами.
Нужно задать размер для двухмерного массива (квадрат) после чего ввести данные для одномерного массива
Введенные данные нужно вывести в виде двухмерного массива змейкой (сверху вниз зигзагом), но у меня выводится снизу верх, также всё должно быть выполнено в виде подпрограмм, пример вывода, чтобы было понятнее:
Что я в теории должен получить:

размер - 3

элементы одномерного массива - `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`

вывод двухмерного массива :

```
1 6 7
2 5 8
3 4 9
```

Что я получаю :

вывод двухмерного массива :

```
3 4 9
2 5 8
1 6 7
```

Помогите пожалуйста, не могу понять в чём проблема, и пожалуйста желательно (но не обязательно),
чтобы массив выводился правильно для разных размеров, не только 3*3, но повторяю это не обязательно,
главное чтобы проблема была решена.

```
/**************************************************************************************/
/*                                                                                    */
/* Задание: создать программу средствами языка С ++, для формирования двухмерного     */
/*массива a[n][n] путём чтения с него данных с заданного одномерного                  */
/*массиву b[m*n] согласно индивидуального варианта.                                   */
/*   1 6 7                                                                            */
/*   2 5 8                                                                            */ 
/*   3 4 9                                                                            */
/* Протестировать программу по трем разным наборам данных.                            */
/**************************************************************************************/

#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define MAX 100

using namespace std;

float a[MAX][MAX], b[MAX];

int InpSizes(int* n, int* k);                                   // Ввод размеров
int InpOneDimArr(float b[MAX], int* k);                         // Введение одномерного массива b
int OutOneDimArr(float b[MAX], int* k);                         // Вывод одномерного массива b
int SetValues(float a[][MAX], float b[], int* n, int* k);       // Заполнение двухмерного массива а
int OutTwoDimArr(float a[][MAX], int* n);                       // Вывод двухмерного массива а

int main() {

    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    float a[MAX][MAX];
    float b[MAX];

    // Ввод размеров
    int n = 0, k = 0;
    InpSizes(&n, &k);

    // Вводим элементы массива b
    InpOneDimArr(b, &k);

    // Вывод масива b
    OutOneDimArr(b, &k);

    OutTwoDimArr(a, &n);

    SetValues(a, b, &n, &k);

    // Вывод массива а
    OutTwoDimArr(a, &n);


    return 0;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int SetValues(float a[][MAX], float b[], int* n, int* k) {
    // вспомогательные переменные
    int filler = 0;      // Заполнитель
    int collumn, row;    // Столбцы и строки
    while (filler < *k) {
        for (collumn = 0; collumn <= *n; collumn++) {
            if ( collumn % 2 != 0) {
                for (row = 0; row < *n; row++) {
                    //if (row + collumn <= *n) {
                        *(*(a + row) + collumn) = *(b + filler);
                        ++filler;
                    //}
                }
            }
            else {
                for (row = *n - 1; row >= 0; row--) {
                    //if (row + collumn <= *n) {
                        *(*(a + row) + collumn) = *(b + filler);
                        ++filler;
                    //}
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Ввод размеров
int InpSizes(int* n, int* k){
    cout << endl <<" Введите количество строк и столбцов двухмерного массива:";
    cin >> *n;

    // Размер массива a
    *k =*n * *n;
    return 0;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Подпрограмма ввода элементов одномерного массива
int InpOneDimArr(float b[MAX], int* k) {
    for (int i = 0; i < *k; i++) {
        cout << endl << "Введите значение [" << i << "] элемента:";
        cin >> *(b + i);
    }
    return 0;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Подпрограмма вывода одномерного массива
int OutOneDimArr(float b[MAX], int* k) {
    cout << endl << "   Элементы массива b:" << endl << "\t";
    for (int i = 0; i < *k; i++) {
        cout << *(b + i) << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Подпрограмма вывода двухмерного массива
int OutTwoDimArr(float a[][MAX], int* n) {
    cout << endl << "   Элементы массива а:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < *n; i++) {
        cout << "\t";
        for (int j = 0; j < *n; j++) {
            cout << *(*(a + i) + j) << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Для того, чтобы перевернуть ваш вывод просто измените обход вашего двумерного массива, чтобы он обходил строки в порядке обратном нынешнему

Answer (score 0):

Так, проблема решена, немного затупил, жаль никто не помог, но не суть.
Проблема решается довольно легко, в подпрограмме `int SetValues`, замените местами `for (row = 0; row < *n; row++)` и `for (row = *n - 1; row >= 0; row--)` и массив начнёт выводить результаты правильно